# Deploy two different apps on different ports

Tags: apache, ubuntu, deployment, reverse-proxy

The question is quite simple. How two deploy two different Nodejs apps on ubuntu 20 remote server. App1 should accessed throw http://ip-address:8080 and Second App should be deployed on http://ip-address:8081. This two app always are accessible from localhost.  My web server is apache and this two port are disabled in firewall.

So `ufw status` return below result

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8081                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8081 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and my apache2 configured to reverse proxy like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's usually difficult to describe simple things, so you should edit the question to include more information, such as what exactly are the web apps? If they indeed work on localhost:8080 and localhost:8081, and you want them to be accessible from outside, you should first check their bindings and force them to bind to non-localhost, not reverse proxying.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Apache by giving the direct path for both the cases. how will apache know which request should be redirected to which port ?

Answer:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/

ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8081/
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

I hopefully believe this should resolve your issue if other configurations are in place. any further errors should be investigated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1

ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost:8081/app2
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:8081/app2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).